# Vultr Docker Setup With SSL

Tags: docker, dockerfile, lets-encrypt, vultr

I'm trying to spin up a dockerized website (React JS) being hosted on my Vultr server. I used the one click install feature that Vultr provides to install Docker (Ubuntu 20.04).

I can get my website started with HTTP and a port number 8080. But what I'm looking to accomplish are the following:

1. How to add SSL to my website with docker(since my website is dockerized).

PS: I already have a domain name.

2. How to get rid of the port number as it doesn't look very professional.

For number 2, I did try adding a reverse proxy but not sure if I did it correctly.

Also, not sure if this was the right approach, but I did install letsencrypt in my host Vultr machine (nginx was need too for some reason). I navigated to my domain name and sure enough I do see my website secured (https) with the "Welcome to Nginx" landing page. But again, is this the correct way? If so, how do I display my react website secured instead of the default "Welcome to Nginx" landing page.

Or should I have not installed nginx or letsencrypt in the host machine?

As you can see, I'm an absolute beginner in docker!

This is my Dockerfile-prod

```
FROM node as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn cache clean && yarn --update-checksums
COPY . ./
RUN yarn && yarn build

# Stage - Production
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443

#Make sites-available directory
RUN mkdir "etc/nginx/sites-available"

#Make sites-enabled directory
RUN mkdir "etc/nginx/sites-enabled"

# add nginx live config
ADD config/*****.com /etc/nginx/sites-available/*****.com

# create symlinks
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/*****.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*****

# make certs dir as volume
VOLUME ["/etc/letsencrypt"]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have to configuration files. PS: I was trying following this guy's repo [repo](https://gitlab.com/rahasak-labs/nginx-ops/-/tree/master/nginx-letsencrypt)

I feel like everything is there in front of me to get it to work, but I just can't figure it out. If you guys can help me out, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

config 1 *****-live.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *****.com www.*****.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *****.com www.*****.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:8080;
    }
}
```

config 2 *****-staging.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name     *****.com www.*****.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

This is my host machine directory to letsencrypt/live
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nginx Proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and its [acme companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion).

1. Nginx proxy helps you get read of the port name and can route multiple domain through single IP.
2. Acme proxy can create a Let's encrypt SSL for you and automatically renew it.

Follow the instructions in their GitHub README to set them up.